# Farthest vs Furthest

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-choice, terminology, programming

I am trying to describe the distance from a root node in a programming context. The root node is abstract and not physical so I'm thinking the proper usage would be `furthest`, but what would be suggested here:

> CHOICES 
> Closest to root node. 
> Furthest from root node

In this context, would it be more correct to say furthest or farthest?

Comment: You show that you're aware that the key difference is physical vs conceptual distance. Please edit to explain why you have second thoughts about "further"? I assume the decision hinges on the degree to which abstract concepts are being explained using a spatial analogy. Or are you not sure that "closest" can be a valid antonym of "furthest"?

Comment: @AndyBonner right, spatially and numerically, it could be "1 node away", "2 nodes away", etc. So in a way it could be a distance (for example on a number scale).

Answer (score 0):

**Further** is for abstract or non-measurable distances. **Farther** is for physically measurable distances.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-further-or-farther-usage-how-to-use

Comment: well yes, but the number of nodes is quantifiable -- 1, 2, 3 nodes away, for example.

Comment: I think this misrepresents the views put forth in the article (which looks very sound).

Comment: @user1383058 This gives a clue as to which word to use. If it is quantifiable,  measurable, then use farther.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth to clarify, what do you mean by "article" ?

Comment: @user1383058 He is referring to the link to an article in the answer I provided.